# Trying to fire an event after iframe vid ends but got an error instead

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to set up an iframe controller, something like a playlist that allows for YouTube videos to be played in succession but I ma getting an error. Besides the code below I have also tried `.on('ended',)` function. It doesn't return an error but does not fire.

Javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        video = document.getElementById("video");
        alert("aaa");
        console.log(video);
        $('#video').addEventListener('ended', function(){
            console.log("Video ended");
           $(this).attr("src", source);
        });

    });
```

Error

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):52)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)



jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).addEventListener is not a function TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/playlist_item/3/1/:52:17)
    at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using JQuery, you should use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `addEventListener`:

```
$('#video').on('ended', function(){
     console.log("Video ended");
     $(this).attr("src", source);
});
```

Comment: That took away the errors but the event still doesn't fire upon video end. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are listening to the wrong object. You can provide a fiddle if you want further help.

Comment: I think you may be right, tried it on a blank chrome page and the $('#video') highlights the videoplayer but not on my project.